# How to retrieve location information on MacOS?

Tags: macos, geolocation, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I stumbled into **CoreLocation** framework and implemented the basic steps as described in the iOS *[Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1)*, since I could not find one for OSX.

```
// AppDelegate.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager* m_locationManager;
}
@end
```

There is not so much in the implementation file ...

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification {
    m_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    m_locationManager.delegate = self;
    m_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [m_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

When I start the application I am asked to authorize the location lookup. The same question appears again after a while.
**Problem:** However, none of the delegate methods get called.

---

BTW: An interesting article about [Apple and Google Maps](http://www.wallstreetjournal.de/article/SB10001424052702303918204577448180303398226.html?mod=WSJDE_latestheadlines) announcing [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of:

1)

Is your app going to run on MacOS 10.6 & newer?  If so, make sure your project's  "deployment target" setting is set for 10.6 or newer.

2)

In your "`.h`" Interface file, make sure to add `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` to indicate that this object conforms to the protocol. It looks like you're trying to do this from your application delegate, so the declaration might look something like:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Comment: *Mac OS X Deployment Target* is set to *Mac OS X 10.7* and also set the delegate in the header file.

Comment: What kind of machine are you running this on?  I'm not sure that macs have any location hardware for this to work with.

Comment: @rdelmar It's a Mac Pro running Lion. As far as I understand the location API encapsulates WIFI, GPS, .. so it would make no difference what kind of machine I am running this on.

Comment: Well, maybe the code I've tried isn't right, but I've never been able to get location info on my iMac.  I thought I read somewhere (a couple of years ago) that your router had to be registered with some service to have it supply location info.